# Unwrap inner array from a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I transform this `numpy` array:

```
[[[10 10]]
 [[300 300]]
 [[10 300]]]
```

Into this one:

```
[[[ 10  10]
  [300 300]
  [ 10 300]]]
```

Comment: I can't figure out your rules. Why is the given input converted into that specific output?

Comment: Yep, You should give more info on this

Comment: If you want anyone to answer you will need to explain the logic behind the conversion!

Comment: I need the second type to be used in cv2.fillPoly method

Comment: what is `cv2`? an object? a module? post some runable code with and explanation what you're trying to do? asking how to turn `x` into `y` with no other info is far too broad.

Comment: If the example given is supposed to be inconsistent (no single data point in array 1 matches that of array 2, and the total number of data also doesn't match), perhaps [`ndarray.reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) is what you're looking for?

Comment: A Python list representing an array of values or a numpy ndarray?

Comment: The second one is supposed to be a np.array

Comment: Did you check the docs? [```numpy.swapaxes```](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to slice the first item of the subarrays and then wrap that in an outer array:

```
a = numpy.array([[[10, 10]],
     [[300, 300]],
     [[10, 300]]])
b = numpy.array([a[:,0]])
print(b)
```

prints

```
[[[ 10  10]
  [300 300]
  [ 10 300]]]
```

Or, using `swapaxes`:

```
b = numpy.swapaxes(a, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a.reshape((1,3,2))
print(b)
array([[[ 10,  10],
        [300, 300],
        [ 10, 300]]])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit? For example, explanations about interesting parts of your code snippet, or links to the documentation?

Comment: your previous shape was this (3, 1, 2) and the required shape was (1,3,2). Hence the transformation. And it does iff  a*b*c == 3*1*2 in this case